# Filter data using JSON query in Ansible to extract data from an ansible_fact

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2

I have created this playbook to extract all mount points starting with any element in the variable `whitelist` matching the `type= ext2, ext3, ext4`.

The problem is that I can get all `mount_points` but I am not able to filter the result with the variables.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  vars:
     whitelist:
         - /boot
         - /home
         - /opt
         - /var
         - /bin
         - /usr

  tasks:
  - name: extract mount_points 
    set_fact:
      mount_point: "{{ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype', 'in', ['ext2', 'ext3', 'ext4']) | map(attribute='mount') | list }}"

  - debug:
      var: mount_point
    vars:
      query: "[?starts_with(mount, whitelist)].mount"
```

When I execute the playbook I get this

```
ok: [ansible@controller] => {
    "mount_point": [
        "/", 
        "/boot", 
        "/tmp", 
        "/home", 
        "/var", 
        "/var/opt", 
        "/var/tmp", 
        "/var/log", 
        "/var/log/audit", 
        "/opt", 
    ]
}
```

`/tmp` is included which means that `query: "[?starts_with(mount, whitelist)].mount"` was skipped and I don't know how to achieve the playbook goal.

Comment: I'd be happy to propose a solution but I don't quite understand the logic. If you want anything starting with any element of your whitelist, any mount point will match since they all start with `/` which is your first element (i.e. `/tmp` starts with `/`).... can you be a bit more specific about what you expect exactly? Please do not reply in comments, [edit](/posts/72929682/edit) your question.

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you so much. You are right i already modified my question with `/` it will not be logic. I already eliminated it from the variable list.
So the main goal is to find the `mount_points`  with `fstype=ext2,ext3 and ext4` starting the variable `whitelist` for example we get `/var/log/audit` as in `whiteliste` whe `/var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a json query here IMO. An easy way is to filter the list with `match` and construct a regex containing all possible prefixes:

```yaml
- name: show my filtered mountpoints:
  vars:
    start_regex: "{{ whitelist | map('regex_escape') | join('|') }}"
  degug:
    msg: "{{ {{ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype', 'in', ['ext2', 'ext3', 'ext4'])
          | map(attribute='mount') | select('match', start_regex) | list }}"
```

Comment: it's working like a magic thank you so much @Zeitounator.
I have what i am looking for.
`=> { "msg": ["/var", "/home", "/boot", "/opt", "/var/opt", ] }`

Answer (score 0):

While testing i used a filter expression within the `json_query` string which  achieved the same goal for me [Query String with Dynamic Variable](https://blog.networktocode.com/post/ansible-filtering-json-query/)
.
In this example the filter expression is used with a built-in function, `?starts_with`. This function provides a boolean result, based on a match with a search string, on any element within the `fstype` and `mount_point` using a dynamic variable `{{whitelist}}`.

```
- name: find mount_points
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_mounts | to_json | from_json | json_query(mount_point) }}"
  vars:
      mount_point: " @[?starts_with(fstype, 'ext')] | @[?starts_with(mount, '{{item}}')].mount"
  loop: "{{whitelist}}"
```

this is the output

```
ok: [ansible@ansible1] => (item=/var) => {
    "msg": [
        "/var", 
        "/var/opt", 
        "/var/tmp", 
        "/var/log", 
        "/var/log/audit"
}
ok: [ansible@ansible1] => (item=/usr) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [ansible@ansible1] => (item=/home) => {
    "msg": [
        "/home"
>>>
```